# Eager constraint in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table `customers` and a table `orders`. One customer can have many orders. 
I am trying to come up with a query that grabs the first and last order for each customer.

My query as below, using eager loading, but I can only grab either of the two orders for each customer.

```
$customers = Customer::with(array('orders' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('id','desc');

}))
->with(array('orders' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('id', 'asc');

}))
->get();
```

Any idea how to go about doing it in Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify separate 'helper' relations for this:

```
// Suppose it's Use hasMany Order relation and
public function latestOrder()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Order')->orderBy('id', 'desc'); // or instead of orderBy you can use latest() which orders by created_at
}

public function oldestOrder()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Order')->orderBy('id', 'asc'); // orderBy here may be omitted, it's just for clarity
}
```

Then load it just like that:

```
$customers = Customer::with('latestOrder', 'oldestOrder')->get();
```

Side note

Don't use those relations together with the real `orders` relation, as it's a waste of 2 queries. If that's the case use `Collection` methods `$customer->orders->first()` and `last()` instead.